# Firestore cloud functions sending emails stuck with infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I am building a small webshop that sells Wine subscription packages. A first debit request is the INITIAL type and after it is successful our app needs to start a Schedule request that looks something like this:

```
const scheduler = (
    { merchantApi, registrationUuid, startDate, amount },
    callback,
    errorCallback
) => {
    const { apiUser, apiPassword } = merchantApi;
    const data = {
        registrationUuid,
        amount,
        currency: "EUR",
        periodLength: 1,
        periodUnit: "DAY",
        startDateTime: startDate,
        **callbackUrl: "link-to-my-callback-cloud-function"**
    };
    axios.post("link-to-my-scheduler-cloud-function", data, {
            auth: {
                username: apiUser,
                password: apiPassword,
            },
        })
        .then((res) => {
            callback(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            errorCallback(err);
        });
};
```

Based on Gateway docs:
*callbackUrl: Callback Url for sending the Postback notifications of transactions initiated by the schedule to this URL, instead of the URL from the Register transaction. Your system must respond to this request with an HTTP status code 200 and the content OK (without quotes). If your response differs or if no response is given, the Gateway will continue to send the notification in increasing intervals.*

On that callbackUrl URL notification (in JSON format) will be sent after one month (one day in this case because of testing). JSON we get on callbackUrl after certain period of time:

`{ "result": "OK", "uuid": "abcde12345abcde12345", "merchantTransactionId": "2019-09-02-0007", "purchaseId": "20190927-abcde12345abcde12345", "transactionType": "DEBIT", "paymentMethod": "DirectDebit", "amount": "9.99", "currency": "EUR", "customer": { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe", "emailVerified": "false" }, "returnData": { "_TYPE": "cardData", "type": "visa", "cardHolder": "John Doe", "expiryMonth": "12", "expiryYear": "2022", "binDigits": "41111111", "firstSixDigits": "411111", "lastFourDigits": "1111", "fingerprint": "9s92FBBvMuw7nn8t7ChHDRuFXS6gZOnHymbGnO/BZBUw3j25LW6dcl50aHWTcdJtSFDvTqLPM4stZLbGb6EVpQ", "threeDSecure": "OFF", "binBrand": "VISA", "binBank": "JPMORGAN CHASE BANK N.A.", "binType": "", "binLevel": "", "binCountry": "US" } }`

After receiving the notification I need to send an email to the customer about payment:

**link-to-my-callback-cloud-function**

```
exports.callback = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    corsHandler(req, res, async () => {
        try {
            const { amount, currency, customer, merchantTransactionId, returnData } = req.body;
            const { firstName, lastName, email } = customer;
            const { firstSixDigits, lastFourDigits, binBrand } = returnData;
            const data = {
                to: [email],
                message: {
                    subject: 'Email subject',
                    text: 'Email text goes here',
                },
            };
            await admin.firestore().collection('mail').add(data);
            res.status(200).send('OK');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error creating document:', error);
            res.status(500).json({ error: 'Something went wrong' });
        }
    })
});
```

In this function I stuck with infinite loop and I got email every second. Is anyone familiar with this type of the problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).